# Sort matrix by column headers

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I created a matrix that looks like this and has columns order `dev`, `prod`, `test`:

[image]

But I would like to sort the header in this order: `dev`, `test`, `prod`.

I followed this [super easy guide](https://www.excelnaccess.com/custom-sorting-in-power-bi/) but I couldn't sort the matrix in the order I wanted.

I have indeed created the table, the index and sorted the whole thing:

[image]

If you want to help me you can download the files here:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=5cypbz)
- [.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=ptHyg0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the hard work - just use the correct data. Replace this.

[image]

With this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like a baws, Davide!